# Is it possible to use the value returned from one custom hook inside another custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to share application logic between components in my application using custom hooks.  I have a component in my app which updates some state which has it's own custom hook, I then have another component in my application, which also has it's own custom hook, but the state in this one is computed based on changes in state stored in the first custom hook.  What I want to happen is that, when the state is updated in the first custom hook, I want a useEffect hook in the second custom hook to fire to compute the new state for the second component.  I realise when I'm typing this it might sound confusing so I've created a barebones example.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/quiet-voice-sjl5z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

The codesandbox contains a barebones version of what I'm trying to do.  What I want to happen is when I click on the "click me" button in that sandbox the counter in `ComponentTwo.js` should increment.  I'm new to the react hooks API so I'm most likely just not understanding something about the way they work.

Comment: it sounds like you want to use Context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time when you call `useHookOne()` you create a new instance of your hook.

For example. If you add `console.log("hook1", Math.random());` in your `useHookOne` you will see different random values.

[image]

You should use hook `useContext` or redux with hooks `useSelector` and `useDispatch` for sharing data between components and hooks.

**[Example with context here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-currying-bn3n6?file=/src/hooks/Context.jsx)**